# Local static constants in Vala: possible?

Tags: vala

## The land

Vala provides enumerations. But these cannot be defined locally to a sub‑program. Constants can be defined locally to a sub‑program, but seems to not be treated as static expressions (pseudo constants so).

## The case

I have some sub‑programs implemented as state machines built with `switch` statements. I use some `switch (state) { … }` and want to use some constant for the `case` statements, as in `case initial_state: { … }`. This is recommended I believe, as it is more readable and maintainable than using literal constants as in `case 0: { … }`.

I tried to defined these constants inside the sub‑program, using declarations like `const int initial_state = 0;`. But Vala complains at each case statements. I tried to define an enumerations for the states, as in `enum State { initial_state, … };`, but Vala reject this as a syntax error and seems to only allows enumerations declarations outside of sub‑programs.

So far, I have to either define all states enumerations as external to the sub‑programs, or else to define constants inside the sub‑programs, but then have to use `if` constructs instead of `switch` constructs, as it's OK for the `if` condition expression, to not be static.

## The question

Do Vala allows to define static constants (of a scalar type) locally to a sub‑program in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an error from gcc, not valac.  Using this example:

```
private void foo (int val) {
  const int one = 1;
  const int two = 2;
  const int three = 3;

  switch ( val ) {
    case one:
      GLib.debug ("One");
      break;
    case two:
      GLib.debug ("One");
      break;
    case three:
      GLib.debug ("Three");
      break;
    default:
      GLib.debug (val.to_string ());
      break;
  }
}
```

valac will generate:

```
void foo (gint val) {
    static const gint one = 1;
    static const gint two = 2;
    static const gint three = 3;
    gint _tmp0_;
    _tmp0_ = val;
    switch (_tmp0_) {
        case one:
        {
            g_debug ("t.vala:8: One");
            break;
        }
        case two:
        {
            g_debug ("t.vala:11: One");
            break;
        }
        case three:
        {
            g_debug ("t.vala:14: Three");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            gint _tmp1_;
            gchar* _tmp2_ = NULL;
            gchar* _tmp3_;
            _tmp1_ = val;
            _tmp2_ = g_strdup_printf ("%i", _tmp1_);
            _tmp3_ = _tmp2_;
            g_debug ("t.vala:17: %s", _tmp3_);
            _g_free0 (_tmp3_);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

gcc will say something like:

```
t.vala.c:25:3: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
t.vala.c:30:3: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
t.vala.c:35:3: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
```

Interestingly, clang is fine with it (`valac --cc=clang ...`, if you want to play with it).

Comment: Ho, I missed that, I did not noticed the message was from GCC (will have another look at it). So if I understand you correctly, I guess I should submit a but report?

Comment: I honestly don't know whether it is a bug or not.  clang seems to be more forgiving than gcc here, but it's possible that gcc is just following the standards more strictly.

Comment: Well, I will try to submit it as a bug in Vala on LaunchPad (that may also be an error in the C generation), and then see what they think about the case. They will probably have an idea of what's supposed to be the right interpretation.

Comment: Vala doesn't use launchpad for issue tracking.  We use GNOME's bugzilla: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=vala